# Interface as a Property

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface and two classes which implement it. I'm getting a compiler error, and I'm not quite sure why.

```
interface IPerson
{
    ICollection<string> NickNames{get;set;}
}
class ObservablePerson : IPerson
{
    ObservableCollection<string> NickNames{get;set;}
}
class ListPerson : IPerson
{
    List<string> NickNames{get;set;}
}
```

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why this won't work, as List and ObservableCollection both implement ICollection.

Comment: Please state the compiler error.

Comment: @Robert, it would be "ObservablePerson does not implement interface member IPerson.NickNames" and further stuff about non-matching return types. And, for that matter, the implementations must also be public.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the hundreds of variance questions.

Comment: Forgot about the public modifier. And I did not know this is a "variance" question as I'm still learning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why this won't work, as List and ObservableCollection both implement ICollection.

Yes, but the interface states that an `ICollection<string>` is returned.  The underlying type may be an `ObservableCollection<string>` or a `List<string>`, but the signature needs to conform to the interface.  An `ObservableCollection<string>` is an `ICollection<string>`, but an `ICollection<string>` is not necessarily an `ObservableCollection<string>`.

Also, your methods need to be public (they are currently private).  Interfaces don't deal with private or protected methods, it defines the *public* interface.

Comment: Right. For more, look at the fact that the property has a setter. A consumer of `IPerson` should think that he can set the property to *any* `ICollection<string>`, but that's clearly not the case if the provided code could actually compile.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add the public modifier.

Comment: Ok, but do you understand the rational now?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for all the explantions guys!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
interface IPerson
{
    ICollection<string> NickNames{get;set;}
}
class ObservablePerson : IPerson
{
    ICollection<string> NickNames{get;set;}
}
class ListPerson : IPerson
{
    ICollection<string> NickNames{get;set;}
}
```

And inside the implementation, you can return a List object or ObservableCollection

Edited code

```
interface IPerson
    {
        ICollection<string> NickNames{get;set;}
    }

public class ObservablePerson : IPerson
    {
        ICollection<string> nickNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        public ICollection<string> IPerson.NickNames
        {
            get
            {
                return nickNames;
            }
            set
            {
                nickNames = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public class ListPerson : IPerson
    {
        ICollection<string> nickNames = new List<string>();

        public ICollection<string> IPerson.NickNames
        {
            get
            {
                return nickNames;
            }
            set
            {
                nickNames = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: So anyone who uses the ObservablePerson class should just know to cast the NickNames to an ObservableCollection? Or would there be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a similar problem, and a buddy of mine suggested an excellent solution: Generic types. Here's what you can do:

```
public interface IPerson<CollectionType> where CollectionType : ICollection<string>
{
    CollectionType NickNames { get; set; }
}

class ObservablePerson : IPerson<ObservableCollection<string>>
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> NickNames { get; set; }
}

public class ListPerson : IPerson<List<string>>
{
    public List<string> NickNames { get; set; }
}
```

Here, "CollectionType" is a Generic, and can be named whatever you want (It's often called T throughout the .NET Framework, but giving it a meaningful name I feel is helpful). This will allow you to implement an interface on those ObservablePerson and ListPerson, while still having different types for the NickNames property  on each (though any type that you use for CollectionType will need to implement ICollection).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the compiler expects both of your subclasses to return a type of ICollection. You can return a List or ObservableCollection via the get accessor, but the declared member type needs to remain ICollection.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler will insist on exact type matches, but you can shadow the property when accessed on the class (instead of through the interface). Note however, that when setting through the interface someone may assign a different kind of `ICollection<string>` - so this would result in an exception.

```
interface IPerson
{
    ICollection<string> NickNames { get; set; }
}
class ObservablePerson : IPerson
{
    public new ObservableCollection<string> NickNames { get; set; }
    ICollection<string> IPerson.NickNames
    {
        get { return NickNames; }
        set { NickNames = (ObservableCollection<string>)value; }
    }
}
class ListPerson : IPerson
{
    public new List<string> NickNames { get; set; }
    ICollection<string> IPerson.NickNames
    {
        get { return NickNames; }
        set { NickNames = (List<string>)value; }
    }
}
```